# Connect WSL2 SQL Server localhost instance from Windows 10

Tags: sql-server, docker, containers, wsl-2

I had setup a WSL2 Ubuntu. Now I am running a local SQL Server instance on the 1401 port using Docker.

Container port:

> 0.0.0.0:1401->1433/tcp

I would like to connect this instance from SSMS but I am getting following error:

Server name: localhost, 1401
Error:

> Cannot connect to localhost,1401.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>
> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the
> instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow
> remote connections.
>
> (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.)
> (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)

**[Solution]**
I am able to connect it via the WSL2 IP. I run "hostname -I" command in WSL2 and use the same IP in SSMS. And, I am able to make a connection

Comment: Thanks @DaleK. I updated my question. I hope it is fine now.

Comment: Do you have a `localhost` mapping in your `HOSTS` file? `0.0.0.0` and `::` are not `127.0.0.1` nor `::1`, so what happens if you use your machine's IP address instead of `localhost`, e.g.: Server name `192.168.0.47,1401`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning there is no mapping in my hostfile. I also tried to connect with IP. I run the command "cat /etc/resolv.conf" on my WSL2 and fetch the IP.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio doesn't execute inside WSL. Do you get a different IP address when you run `ipconfig` in a Command Prompt or a PowerShell window?

Comment: No Different IP. Also, I am not executing SSMS inside WSL.

Answer (score 6):

First question -- Is there a VPN running/connected in Windows?  If so, ignore the rest of this and suspect *that* first.  Make sure the VPN is not running, stop Docker, issue a `wsl --shutdown`, restart and try again.

Assuming that's not the problem ...

Normally, WSL2 provides a feature known as "localhost forwarding" which allows services/apps on Windows to communicate with the virtualized WSL2 IP using `localhost`.  It essentially takes any localhost traffic that isn't directed to a port bound under Windows and forwards it to the Hyper-V virtual network for WSL2.

All WSL2 instances (including the Docker instance) share the same WSL2 network interface as they are all running in the same virtual machine/kernel.

So you seem to be doing the right thing in attempting to connect to `localhost` from SSMS.

But ... sometimes that localhost forwarding breaks.  There are two common (related) scenarios that can cause this (and perhaps others):

- Hibernation of the Windows host
- Having Windows Fast Startup enabled in Power Manager

First check to make sure you can access 1401 from *within* WSL2:

```
nc -zv localhost 1401
```

*^^^ assumes netcat is installed, which it is by default in the WSL2 Ubuntu distribution.  For other distributions, install it or check connectivity via other methods.*

If that doesn't succeed, then I'd suspect some configuration issue in SQL Server.

If that *does* succeed, then run the same test from the Windows host in PowerShell:

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "localhost" -Port 1401
```

If that doesn't succeed, then I'd suspect a localhost forwarding issue.

*Side note: I'm assuming you are running Docker Desktop, but if you are just running Docker Engine in a WSL2 instance, that's no problem.  Just ignore the Docker Desktop instructions below.*

- First, check if you have a `/etc/wsl.conf` in any of your running WSL2 instances that mention disabling `localhostForwarding`.  I'm assuming no, since that is *not* the default.  However, if you happen to, make sure you set these to `true`.
- Stop all WSL2 services, instances, shells, apps, etc. (including Docker Desktop)
- From PowerShell:

  ```
  wsl --shutdown
  ```
- Then restart Docker Desktop and/or your container and try again

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response. Good news is that I am able to connect it via the WSL2 IP. I run "hostname -I" command in WSL2 and use the same IP in SSMS. And, I am able to make a connection.

Answer (score 2):

If localhost doesn’t work, try use [::1] in the server name. In WSL2, port 1433 is using IP/TCPv6, SSMS some times is not able to resolve localhost to loopback IP [::1].

Source: https://jayfuconsulting.wordpress.com/2020/11/14/sql-server-2019-docker-wsl-2/

Answer (score 1):

One last thing which you could try is to modify the windows host file. I almost tried all the steps mentioned over different link, but all goes in vain. Then I opened the host file which could be accessed using

C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc

Open the host file and uncomment(remove # sign) from  the localhost name resolution section
[image]